# Android : My previous button doesn't work

Tags: android, button

I make expert system application and i have two button (previous and next). Next button is work but when i click previous button it doesn't work. It doesn't back to previous page but directly back to main activity. This is my whole activity :

this is previous button :

```
butBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }

    });
```

And this is the next button :

```
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());


            cfpakar = currentQ.getANSWER();
            if(qid<=4){
                if(answer == rda){
                    cfuser = 0;
                } else {
                    cfuser = 1;
                    tahap1++;
                }


            if(qid < QuestList.size()){
                cf = cfpakar * cfuser;
                currentQ=QuestList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuestActivity.this, Result.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                //Bundle c = new Bundle();
                b.putDouble("score", score); //Your score
                b.putInt("tahap1", tahap1);
                b.putInt("tahap2", tahap2);
                b.putInt("tahap3", tahap3);
                //b.putInt("hasil", hasil);
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me, what should i add to the previous button? Thank you before..

Comment: Your next button appears to be finishing the activity after starting the new one.  You either have to remove the call to `finish()` or start your intended activity (with appropriate result) in the previous button onClick.  I recommend looking into https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Within your previous button block just add an intent like you did for next button that points to the previous activity.

Comment: @CzarMatt I've removed the call to finish() on the next button, but it still back to main activity. Sorry i don't understand how i can start my intended activity in previous button. Can you please describe it? I've read your recommendation but still confuse about it.

Comment: btw @CzarMatt thank you for your answer

Comment: @ScottS first i wanna say thank for your answer. But can you please describe an intent should i call for the previous button? this is my first application, so i still get confused about it.